Count occurencies with multiple criteria from dataframe
I have a dataframe from a large excel sheet with patient data outcomes that includes 20+ columns and thousands of rows. I would like to take out statistics based on multiple criteria. I would like to count all the samples that fulfill many different criteria, not only one or two (10+ criteria) including not matching some criteria.
The data looks something like this, but with many more rows and columns.



Genepanel
Causative
Fenotype
Gender




PID
Negative
SCID
Male


IBMFS
ETV6
Trombocytopenia
Female


IBMFS
Negative
Neutropenia
Female


PID
Negative
Hypogamma
Male



For example I would like to know how many patients fulfil the criteria:
Genepanel == PID, Causative != Negative Gender==Male and Fenotype == Hypogamma
So for this example, this equals 1
I have read so many different suggestions, using groupyby() and value_counts() but can't figure out how to use multiple criteria in an easy way.
Since the criteria change often, I would like to write a code that is easy to modify depending on the criteria.

A simple approach to achieve this is using boolean indexing:
criterias = ((df['Genepanel'] == 'PID') & (df['Causative'] != 'Negative') &(df['Gender'] == 'Male') & (df['Fenotype'] == 'Hypogamma'))
count = df[criterias].shape[0]
print(count)

P.S. according to your criteria, the count is supposed to be 0

Thanks, that was very simple. And you are right, it was 0 patients.. ;-)

is there an easy way to extract the numbers into a new list or datafrane? Or is it better to use another method if I want to extract the stats?
